# Accessing data from other domain, client - MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, cross-domain, rpc

I'am new in web development and now i encountered with problem of cross-domain policy. My MVC web application interact with WCF(RPC-style) service to get some data. While i accessed data WCF via console-client everything is "Ok!".  But when i perform  this in web application i get "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" at this then i access data.

 From colleagues i heard that i need to create and  put "crossdomain.xml"  file into web-application deploying root folder. But where is i need to put this file in debugging mode. For debug i use IISExpress

Comment: `TargetInvocationException` is usually thrown by reflection when the called method threw an exception. The `InnerException` property should indicate where the problem lies. Also, can you provide the source code that shows the problem?

Comment: @Mike Dimmick `InnerException` is `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` {"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error...."}

Comment: I think the cross-domain idea is a red herring. I'd interpret the `FaultException` to mean that the service was called successfully but it threw an exception. See if there are any logs on the server (if you have access). If there aren't any, you could enable tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx